# Promise rejecting in function

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, promise

In javascript how can I reject a promise? Simply returning `new Error('blah')` doesnt work right error console throws ".then is not a function" or something like that.

So I included Promise.jsm and then did `return Promise.reject(new Error('blah'))` so my question is: if im in a promise like: then i dont have to return Promise.rject and can just return new Error right?

```
 //mainPromise chains to promise0 and chains to promise1
function doPromise(rejectRightAway) {
    if (rejectRightAway) {
        return Promise.reject(new Error('intending to throw mainPromise rejection')); //is this right place to use Promise.reject? //returning just new Error throws in error console, something like: '.then is not a function' and points to the onReject function of mainPromise.then
    }

    promise0.then(
        function () {

            var promise1 = somePromiseObject;
            promise1.then(
                function () {
                    alert('promise1 success');
                },
                function (aRejReason) {
                    alert('promise1 rejected ' + aRejReason.message);
                    return new Error('promise1 rejected so through promise0 rej then mainPromise rej'); //want to throw promise1 rejection //ok to just return new Error?
                }
            );
        },
        function (aRejReason) {
            alert('promise0 rejected with reason = ' + aRejReason.message);
        }
    );

    return promise0;

}

var mainPromise = doPromise();
mainPromise.then(
    function () {
        alert('mainPromise success');
    },
    function (aRejectReason) {
        alert('mainPromise rejected with reason = ' + aRejectReason.message)
    }
);
```

im not sure if this code works, so my question is how do i reject --- like when is it right to return `Promise.reject(new Error())` and when to just `new Error()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tl:dr

- In order to indicate normal completion of an operation, you return its result `return result`.
- In order to indicate an exception, you `throw new Error(reason)` just like in synchronous code, promises are throw safe.
- It is possible to explicitly return rejections from chains, but often unneeded.

---

One of the great things about promises is that they fix exception handling in asynchronous code.

Promises are not just a < buzzwords> composing sequential monadic DSL < /buzzwords> abstraction over concurrency  - they are also throw safe!

Throw safety is really awesome in this regard, you can act just like ou would in sequential code:

```
function foo(){
    if(somethingWrong){
        // instead of returning normally, we throw, using the built in exception chain
        // code blocks have. This indicates something unexpected breaking the sequence of cour code
        throw new Error("Something was wrong");
    }
    return "some normal result"; // here we indicate a function terminated normally,
                                 // and with which value.
}
```

Callbacks in node use the `(err,result...)` convention which I find ugly. With promises, You gain the benefits of error handling you have in sequential code again:

```
somePromise.then(function(){
     if(rejectRightAway){
          throw new Error("rejecting right away...");
     }
     return "some normal result";
})....
```

See how similar it is to sequential code? Whenever you want to reject you `throw` from the then handler, whenever you want to fulfill you return from the then handler. Just like in "synchronous" code.

So in your case:

```
//want to throw promise1 rejection //ok to just return new Error?
return new Error('promise1 rejected so through promise0 rej then mainPromise rej');
```

Is solved exactly with what you intuitively wanted to do:

```
 throw new Error("promise1 rejected so through promise0 rej then mainPromise rej");
```

Comment: Note some libraries (namely $q) treat `throw` statements somewhat more severely than `$q.reject` returns and will log them to the console. Logging errors to the console in case the library can't track unhandled rejections for you is actually a good thing imo.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to reject the specific promise:

```
return promise0.reject(new Error('intending to throw mainPromise rejection'));
```

Comment: ah simply returning new Error wont start the rejection of the chain?

Comment: @Noitidart Correct, you need to reject the promise.

Comment: ah ok so if I did return `Promise.reject(` instead of `promise0.reject` would it recognize which promise im trying to reject?

Comment: i cant do `mainPromise.reject` in the `rejectRightAway` clause, it throws a weird error saying `then is not a function`

Comment: You can't do `Promise.reject` as it can't tell what promise *to* reject.  I'm not sure why you have two promises in your question, why don't you just attach `.then`s to the first promise?

Comment: to mainPromise? because i need to call a reusable function, different areas can call this. mainPromise does have a .then (i did a bunch of edits on the code)